# adding calendar on form field in magento 2 not working error 404

Tags: magento2, datepicker, calendar

In frontend I've managed to add a form that loads in a modal shown after a product is added to cart. On that form a field must have a calendar on. I've used the attribute `data-mage-init='{"calendar": {"showTime": false, "showOn":"both", "defaultDate":"-20y"}}'` on the form field. 
But on the console I see

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://testmagento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/calendar.js"
>   .

Indeed in that location there is no calendar.js. Instead I've found the calendar.js under http://testmagento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.js

I can't figure out the problem. 
Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

ok... so the last idea I came up with was to include the following script inside .phtml file, and not use the data-mage-init attribute anymore:

> ```
> <form action="" method="POST">
>         <label for="name">Name: </label>
>         <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/><br>
> ....
>         <label for="birthdate">Birth date: </label>
>         <input type="text" id="birthdate" name="birthdate"/><br>
> </form>
>     <script>
>         require([
>             "jquery",
>             "mage/calendar"
>         ], function($){
>
>             $("#birthdate").calendar({
>                 showTime: false,
>                 //dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
>             });
>         });
>     </script>
> ```